# Entire <td> as checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make an entire `td` a checkbox, which will change colors when clicked (and change checkbox value to checked). The `td`'s behavior will be:

- When unchecked, the `td`'s background color will be white
- When checked, the `td`'s background color will change to red
- There'll be no checkbox since the entire `td` will be the checkbox

ANOTHER EDIT: Here's [how](https://jsfiddle.net/L6w1khtq/) I implement it

EDIT: Here's the code, which is incomplete, (this is just a draft)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Header</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/primary.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" async></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripter.js" async></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="table">
            <!-- <form method="POST"> -->
                    <table id='sample'>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Time\Date</th>
                                <th>Monday</th>
                                <th>Tuesday</th>
                                <th>Wednesday</th>
                                <th>Thursday</th>
                                <th>Friday</th>
                                <th>Saturday</th>
                                <th>Sunday</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>07:30-08:00</td>
                                <td id="A1" onclick="this.bgColor=='#FFFFFF' ? this.bgColor='#FF0000' : this.bgColor='#FFFFFF'"><input type="checkbox" >A1</input></td>
                                <td id="B1" onclick="this.bgColor=='#FFFFFF' ? this.bgColor='#FF0000' : this.bgColor='#FFFFFF'">B1</td>
                                <td id="C1" onclick="this.bgColor=='#FFFFFF' ? this.bgColor='#FF0000' : this.bgColor='#FFFFFF'">C1</td>
                                <td id="D1" onclick="this.bgColor=='#FFFFFF' ? this.bgColor='#FF0000' : this.bgColor='#FFFFFF'">D1</td>
                                <td id="E1" onclick="this.bgColor=='#FFFFFF' ? this.bgColor='#FF0000' : this.bgColor='#FFFFFF'">E1</td>
                                <td id="F1" onclick="this.bgColor=='#FFFFFF' ? this.bgColor='#FF0000' : this.bgColor='#FFFFFF'">F1</td>
                                <td id="G1" onclick="this.bgColor=='#FFFFFF' ? this.bgColor='#FF0000' : this.bgColor='#FFFFFF'">G1</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>08:00-08:30</td>
                                <td>A1</td>
                                <td>B1</td>
                                <td>C1</td>
                                <td>D1</td>
                                <td>E1</td>
                                <td>F1</td>
                                <td>G1</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>08:30-09:00</td>
                                <td>A1</td>
                                <td>B1</td>
                                <td>C1</td>
                                <td>D1</td>
                                <td>E1</td>
                                <td>F1</td>
                                <td>G1</td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
            <!-- </form> -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show the tried code!

Comment: if you don't use the checkbox, why in the first place have a checkbox, you can do your logic using a click listener.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you the idea of how to implement it you can try that and if not then will help.

What you can do is make the td have a check box but make it display none.

When the user clicks on the td element trigger that check box to on and off and based on the on and off i.e. checked and unchecked you can set the css for styling as per your requirement

Comment: I got the idea, here's [how](https://jsfiddle.net/L6w1khtq/) I implement it

Comment: Great you did it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo, Hope it can help!

```js
var checked=false;
var checkbox=document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox")[0];
function toggleCheckbox(){
  checked = !checked;
  if(checked){
   checkbox.classList.add("checked");
  }else{
   checkbox.classList.remove("checked");
  }
}
```

```css
.checkbox{
   width:25px;
   height:25px;
   border:1px solid red;
   cursor:pointer;
   text-align:center;
}

.checked{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="checkbox" onclick="toggleCheckbox()"></td>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Colony</td>
    <td>4456</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```